# Magento connect manager - Dangerous to install upgrades above Magento version?

Tags: magento

I'm wanting to know if it's safe for me to upgrade any of the packages which have upgrades available. My Magento version is 1.6...but there seem to be upgrades which include numbers 1.6.2.2 , 1.7 etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that only clean Magento installation can be upgraded through the Magento Connect. It other ways if you do not have unit and acceptance tests, it's too risky to use the Magento Connect.